# on_connect callback continuously called

Tags: c++, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a simple C++ application running locally on the same box as a Mosquitto broker. I was doing some debugging of my application and I noticed the on_connect callback kept continuously firing, and the broker keeps showing the following 2 lines.

```
New Client connected from 10.0.2.37 as publisher-test
Client publisher-test already connected, closing old connection
```

This seems like odd behavior, and I would like to figure out how to stop it from happening.

Here is my code that sets up mqtt client and initiates the connection to the broker.

```
bool MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto() {
    int rc = mosquitto_lib_init();
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #1 - mosquitto_lib_init %s \r\n", rc==MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS ? "succeeded" : "failed");
    mMosq = mosquitto_new("publisher-test", true, NULL);
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #2A %x %s \r\n",&mMosq, mMosq == NULL ? "failed to create mosquitto obj": "successfully created mosquitto obj");
    mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mMosq, on_connect_callback);
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #2B mosquitto_connect_callback_set \r\n");
    mosquitto_publish_callback_set(mMosq, on_pub_callback);
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #2C mosquitto_publish_callback_set \r\n");
    mosquitto_subscribe_callback_set(mMosq, on_sub_callback);
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #2D mosquitto_subscribe_callback_set \r\n");
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(mMosq, on_msg_callback);
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #2E mosquitto_message_callback_set \r\n");
    mosquitto_user_data_set(mMosq,  this);
    printf("MosquittoAppServers::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #2F mosquitto_user_data_set \r\n");
    rc = mosquitto_username_pw_set(mMosq, "mqtt_user", "P@$$#123");
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #3 mosquitto_username_pw_set %s \r\n", rc==MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS ? "succeeded" : "failed");
    
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #4 about to connect to broker at address: %s \r\n", mBrokerIpAddr);
    
    rc = -1;
    rc = mosquitto_connect(mMosq, mBrokerIpAddr, 1883, 60);
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #5 mosquitto_connect %s \r\n", rc==MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS ? "succeeded" : "failed");
    if(rc != 0) {
        printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Client could not connect to MQTT-Broker!  Error Code: %d\n", rc);
      switch(rc) {
        case MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS:{
            printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto failed to connect.  Received Error MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS \n");
            break;
        }
        case MOSQ_ERR_INVAL:{
            printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto failed to connect.  Received Error MOSQ_ERR_INVAL \n");
            break;
        }
        case MOSQ_ERR_NOMEM:{
            printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto failed to connect.  Received Error MOSQ_ERR_NOMEM \n");
            break;
        }
        case MOSQ_ERR_NO_CONN:{
            printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto failed to connect.  Received Error MOSQ_ERR_NO_CONN \n");
            break;
        }
        case MOSQ_ERR_PROTOCOL:{
            printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto failed to connect.  Received Error MOSQ_ERR_PROTOCOL \n");
            break;
        }
        case MOSQ_ERR_PAYLOAD_SIZE:{
            printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto failed to connect.  Received Error MOSQ_ERR_PAYLOAD_SIZE \n");
            break;
        }
        case MOSQ_ERR_MALFORMED_UTF8:{
            printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto failed to connect.  Received Error MOSQ_ERR_MALFORMED_UTF8 \n");
            break;
        }
        case MOSQ_ERR_QOS_NOT_SUPPORTED:{
            printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto failed to connect.  Received Error MOSQ_ERR_QOS_NOT_SUPPORTED \n");
            break;
        }
        case MOSQ_ERR_OVERSIZE_PACKET:{
            printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto failed to connect.  Received Error MOSQ_ERR_OVERSIZE_PACKET \n");
            break;
        }
      }
        mosquitto_destroy(mMosq);
        return;// -1;
    }
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #6 - Now connected to the broker \r\n");  
    rc = mosquitto_publish(mMosq, NULL, "my-mqtt-topic", sizeof("Hello from a cleint!"), "Hello from a client!", 0, false);     
    rc = mosquitto_loop_start(mMosq);
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint #8  - mosquitto_loop_start  result: %s \r\n", rc==MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS ? "succeeded" : "failed");
    
    printf("MosquittoAppServer::InitMosquitto Breeakpoint THE END \r\n");
    
    return rc == 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know about Mosquitto, but have you checked whether it's an issue of the client from10.0.2.37?

Comment: @LouisGo the source code above is for the client connecting from 10.0.2.37

Comment: What else do you have running? If you have something else running that connects with the client id `publisher-test` then that will be the issue (when a new client connects the broker will drop any existing connection with that client id - if both clients auto reconnect then you get a continual disconnect/reconnect cycle).

Comment: @Brits good thought, but unfortunately, whenever I terminate my program and I look at the broker output the constant connections from publisher-test stop.  Based on debugging messages my function that initializes mosquito and makes the connection is only being called one time.

Comment: it seems like it has something to do with my keepAlive value which is set in mosquitto_connect() which I was just sticking with a default value of 60.  If I set it to 0 my application doesn't appear to connect to the broker.  I have kind of ruled out my broker because I get the same behavior if I used test.mosquitto.org as the broker.  No matter what value is used in keepAlive it seems like the connects happen at the same rate.

Comment: "whenever I terminate my program.." this is expected (your program stops, the other program connects and that connection stays up). The easiest way to eliminate this as a possible cause is to change the ClientID your program uses. Note that I'd expect to see the same issue when using a common client ID like `publisher-test` on `test.mosquitto.org` because someone else will probably be using that ID too (it's best to use a long, random ID with public brokers). Lets completely eliminate this as a possible cause before investigating other avenues. Mosquitto will reject keepAlive of 0 by default.

Comment: @Brits thanks for your help.  I had a code review today and my connect function was in fact being called twice, but the debugging went by so fast it was impossible to see.  I appreciate your thoughts on my issue.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the scenario my application would initialize mosquitto twice and the result was two loops constantly trying to connect to the broker.